# Where to find the header file and lib file corresponding to Microsoft DLL (say WTTLog.DLL)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries, header-files

Say, you are having a Microsoft DLL (for example WTTLog.DLL that comes with the WinSDK and gets saved in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\x64" when Win8 SDK is installed.

2 questions here::

1)  How and where can I find the header file **exactly corresponding to this version of the DLL**?
    The header file version should be same as the DLL version (32bit/64bit)  because, the mangled names of the function i.e. the "decorated names" of the function should match for both header file and DLL.

2) And where can I find the "*.lib" file corresponding to this version of the DLL ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong on quite a few points.

1. You're assuming that every DLL has a header file. In reality, there may be 0, 1 or more than 1.
2. You're assuming that 64 bits DLL's have different headers. This is obviously untrue, just think of `<windows.h>`.
3. You're assuming that DLL versions are in exact sync with headers. Again, think of `<windows.h>`.
4. You're assuming that function names in a DLL are mangled, in particular re. 32/64 bits. Just think of `LoadLibrary(L"MessageBoxW")` - that is the mangled name, and "W" only means Unicode. Not 64 bits.
5. You're assuming that every DLL has a .lib file. Equally untrue. Why would a COM component DLL need one?